# Weird error with an if statement

Tags: c++

Here's my code, which throws a weird error. I googled around a bit, but I have no idea about what's wrong. The error happes somewhere in the if statement. StackOverflow complains about too much code, but I don't really know what I should add.

Error:

```
Game.cpp:129:73: error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (bool)’
```

Code:

```
bool Game::checkStartAdjacents() {
    for(int i = 0; i < this->floodedTiles.size(); i++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {

                Tile* candidate = this->tileMap[x][y];

                if(candidate->flooded == false 
                        && candidate->color == this->floodedTiles[i]->color (
                        (candidate->x == this->floodedTiles[i]->x 
                        && candidate->y == this->floodedTiles[i]->y - 1) // candidate is above
                        || (candidate->x == this->floodedTiles[i]->x
                        && candidate->y == this->floodedTiles[i]->y + 1) // candidate is below
                        || (candidate->y == this->floodedTiles[i]->y
                        && candidate->x == this->floodedTiles[i]->x - 1) // candidate is to the left
                        || (candidate->y == this->floodedTiles[i]->y
                        && candidate->x == this->floodedTiles[i]->x + 1))) { // THE ERROR HAPPENS AT THIS LINE

                    floodTile(candidate);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is the Tile class:

```
#include <string>

#ifndef TILE_H
#define TILE_H

using namespace std;

class Tile {
public:
    Tile(string color, int x, int y);
    Tile(const Tile& orig);
    virtual ~Tile();
    string color;
    int x;
    int y;
    bool flooded;
private:

};
```

CPP File

```
#include "Tile.h"

Tile::Tile(string color, int x, int y) {
    this->color = color;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    flooded = false;
}

Tile::Tile(const Tile& orig) {
}

Tile::~Tile() {
}
```

Comment: Could you signal which line is 129, where the error is? Also, most compiler errors come in cascade, you should paste all of them, not just this one.

Comment: Why all the `this->` business?

Comment: we need the exact position of the error and the types involved. The error basically says that the compiler tries to create a `std::string` from `bool`. It might be something implicit. We need the types involved.

Comment: Please don't use the C tag when you're not asking about C.

Comment: What is the definition of `Tile`?

Comment: @bolov: Actually, that would be: _no matching function for call to `std::string::string(bool)`_. The error says _no matching function for call to `(std::string)(bool)`_, that actually would be `std::string::operator()(bool)` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if(candidate->flooded == false 
                && candidate->color == this->floodedTiles[i]->color && (
//                                                   forgotten this ^^            

        if(candidate->flooded == false 
                && candidate->color == this->floodedTiles[i]->color || (
//                                                          or that ^^
```

Comment: Hey, maybe `Tile::color` is a function pointer and this has nothing to do with the error...

Comment: @rodrigo, a very unlikely possibility